# Using yt-dlp in a Python script, how do I download a specific section of a video?

Tags: python, youtube, yt-dlp

I'm trying to write a Python script that downloads specific sections of videos using yt-dlp.

```
import yt_dlp

yt_opts = {
    'verbose': True,
    'download_sections': [{
        'section': {
            'start_time': 2,
            'end_time': 7
        }
    }]
}

ydl = yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(yt_opts)

ydl.download("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxUS1K7xu30")
```

I expected this to download the video from 2 seconds to 7, as per the reference [here](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/blob/master/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py#L439-L446). This actually downloads the entire video.

> [debug] Encodings: locale cp1252, fs utf-8, pref cp1252, out utf-8,
> error utf-8, screen utf-8  [debug] yt-dlp version 2022.08.19 [48c88e0]
> (pip)  [debug] Python 3.10.6 (CPython 64bit) -
> Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0   [debug] Checking exe version: ffmpeg -bsfs
> [debug] Checking exe version: ffprobe -bsfs  [debug] exe versions:
> none  [debug] Optional libraries: Cryptodome-3.15.0, brotli-1.0.9,
> certifi-2022.06.15, mutagen-1.45.1, sqlite3-2.6.0, websockets-10.3
> [debug] Proxy map: {}  [debug] [youtube] Extracting URL:
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxUS1K7xu30  [youtube] BxUS1K7xu30:
> Downloading webpage  [youtube] BxUS1K7xu30: Downloading android player
> API JSON  [debug] Sort order given by extractor: quality, res, fps,
> hdr:12, source, vcodec:vp9.2, channels, acodec, lang, proto  [debug]
> Formats sorted by: hasvid, ie_pref, quality, res, fps, hdr:12(7),
> source, vcodec:vp9.2(10), channels, acodec, lang, proto, filesize,
> fs_approx, tbr, vbr, abr, asr, vext, aext, hasaud, id  [debug] Default
> format spec: best/bestvideo+bestaudio  [info] BxUS1K7xu30: Downloading
> 1 format(s): 22  [debug] Invoking http downloader on
> "https://rr2---sn-ab5l6nrd.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1661691812&ei=RBMLY6GdC5CR2LYP5OaJyAU&ip=98.2.224.68&id=o-AIi857cLRkqbZzQpqEAoGwELFeyM_FqC4hfs2P24lLbK&itag=22&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=Rx&mm=31%2C26&mn=sn-ab5l6nrd%2Csn-vgqsrned&ms=au%2Conr&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=15&initcwndbps=2861250&spc=lT-KhhV_37ir7IXjdc7-8htrHPmO2eY&vprv=1&svpuc=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&cnr=14&ratebypass=yes&dur=542.673&lmt=1610233906593465&mt=1661669832&fvip=3&fexp=24001373%2C24007246&c=ANDROID&rbqsm=fr&txp=5535432&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cspc%2Cvprv%2Csvpuc%2Cmime%2Ccnr%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRQIhANDQ2r6ktEGD59h9z22QuZQ9J3Tl_EN56_UzP5Hj7M4UAiBVR7vQOBCoLQjZClr43uEfIr6Ga3IeQx05D2zML9FoPw%3D%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRQIhAJ3w_I3PKsyNWp0rGC2-y-DI4qHgQnyEfP6WxDKs5Gz9AiB_XvzG2yDBJ0D4hzyudyruuztdYxcBYWsH-CSvISnjeg%3D%3D"
> [debug] File locking is not supported. Proceeding without locking
> [download] Destination: The Ideal Gas Law： Crash Course Chemistry #12
> [BxUS1K7xu30].mp4

I've tried to write the 'download_sections' definition several different ways, but I can't find the right one. Do I need to write the definition differently or apply this option in another place entirely?

Comment: AFAIK [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/388148/523431) is the *easiest* way to get things working.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, the Python API for *yt-dlp* doesn't mention the option `download_sections`, instead we have the option `download_ranges` :

[Current Documentation](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/blob/c54ddfba0f7d68034339426223d75373c5fc86df/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py#L457) :

> ```
> download_ranges:   A callback function that gets called for every video with
>                    the signature (info_dict, ydl) -> Iterable[Section].
>                    Only the returned sections will be downloaded.
>                    Each Section is a dict with the following keys:
>                    * start_time: Start time of the section in seconds
>                    * end_time: End time of the section in seconds
>                    * title: Section title (Optional)
>                    * index: Section number (Optional)
> force_keyframes_at_cuts: Re-encode the video when downloading ranges to get precise cuts
> ```

---

So we have to define `download_ranges` as a *callable* taking 2 arguments `(info_dict, ydl)` and returning an *iterable* with the different sections details.

A convenient way is to use the class `download_range_func` as below :

```
import yt_dlp
from yt_dlp.utils import download_range_func

start_time = 2  # accepts decimal value like 2.3
end_time = 7  

yt_opts = {
    'verbose': True,
    'download_ranges': download_range_func(None, [(start_time, end_time)]),
    'force_keyframes_at_cuts': True,
}

with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(yt_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxUS1K7xu30")
```

**Don't forget `force_keyframes_at_cuts` if you want a precise cut.**

---

Another way is to define a simple callable like a lambda function. The following example works but it may shortcut some process (like the convenient negative timestamp). It should be better to implement a class that mimics [download_range_func](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/blob/c54ddfba0f7d68034339426223d75373c5fc86df/yt_dlp/utils/_utils.py#L3260).

```
yt_opts = {
    'download_ranges': lambda info_dict, yt_instance: [
        {'start_time': 2, 'end_time': 7, 'title': 'first_section'},
    ],
    'force_keyframes_at_cuts': True,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also add the format you want, otherwise the downloaded file will be bugged if the starttime is anything else than 0

`yt_opts = { 'format': 'best[ext=mp4]', 'download_ranges': download_range_func(None, [(start_time, end_time)]), 'force_keyframes_at_cuts': True, }`